# .htaccess hiding missing images (and space the image was supposed to fill)

Tags: .htaccess

I found this piece of code here to hide a missing image, it works well, although I am wondering if it could be adapted to do 2 things...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp)$ /images/empty.gif [L]
```

1) Limit the action of this script to one folder only (I tried to create a .htaccess in the folder in question with no success), this script does not work unless it is in the root folder, and it applies to the whole site.

2) This script replaces the image with another one (even transparent), but if the image had width and height, in some context, we see the space of the image, could we adapt the script so it hides the space?

Note, I saw some jquery or javascript that does it, but it is not a good solution for me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparency and image resizing cannot be handled by rewrite rules unless input image provides this information and you have different empty images as replacements.

For requirement #1 you can place this in `/admin/.htaccess/:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.+?\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)$ /images/empty.gif [L,NC]
```

Replace `folder1` with your actual folder name.